# ReferenceError: document is not defined for easy JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, web, puppeteer

I have a method that stores the title of an articel in an Json but the problem is hat a => a.textContent shows `"\n           title            "` of h1. if i use innerText it gives me empty String.

```
const heading = await page.$eval(".boxedarticle--title", h1 => h1.textContent);
```

I read that `var text = "textContent" in document ? "textContent" : "innerText"; document.title = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0][text]` should solve it but then i get the error message `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: The HTML Code:  '<h1 id="viewad-title" class="boxedarticle--title" itemprop="name">title</h1>'

Comment: Are you using this on the frontend? Be great if you could share some of the actual code.

Comment: `async function getDetails(url,page,link) {
    await page.goto(url);                                                                                                     
    let element = await page.$('.boxedarticle--title')
    let heading = await element.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, element)                             
    const preis = await page.$eval('.boxedarticle--price', price => price.textContent);        return {
        title: heading,
        price: preis,
        links: link
    } }`  This is the function that gets the url and page to get further details about heading...

Comment: So its not like it doesnt work with textContent but it contains "\n" in the result String and i dont want them @LeeMorgan

Comment: Can you try `h1.textContent.trim()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey if the `textContent` returns it like this then only possible solution is to handle it at your end like this:

```
a => a.textContent.split('/n')[1].trim()
```

But you must be sure that it always return like `'/n       helllloo       '`